# All possible ways of ordering n values

Tags: r, combinations, interaction

Here is a vector:

```
myVect = c(1,6,3,12,11,15,7,9,19,21)
```

How can get a list of all possible different vectors we can get by reordering `myVect`?

one possible way of reordering can be obtained with:

```
set.seed(12)
sample(myVect)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `permn` from combinat package

```
library(combinat)
permn(myVect)
```

It'll take a while since the number of all possible combinations is 3628800